# Javascript Function Runs Once

Tags: javascript, php, python, refresh

I've made a Javascript script that successfully pulls from a SQLite database that is concurrently being added to by a Python script. I couldn't figure out CGI, but I have this working... to an extent.

When I first run the page, it works fine. It successfully pulls the last entered value for each of my columns using PHP, stores those values into independent Javascript variables, cleans them up so it's just the data, then prints them. Here's an example of what I see when the entire script is executed a single time:

[image]

Here's the problem: the refresh button does not work. The button itself has the following code:

```
<button onclick="grabLatestRecord()">Refresh</button>
```

The entire script is here: http://pastebin.com/Ym74DhJU

I tried adding a refresh function so after the cleaned data is printed it is sent to the refresh function, which then starts the process over, but that didn't work. It has to be something with the PHP, right?

Comment: [AJAX - Getting Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: You're outputting PHP directly into the JS. The PHP is only run once. You probably need to read up about AJAX.

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ I don't understand why it is not executed each time I try to assign a new value to the temp, humidity, and time variables. Why does it not work as if I set it equal to function, where that function returns a value that is then assigned to the variable?

Comment: PHP is server-side, it runs once per request, you need to use AJAX to send another request to the server to get another result.

Comment: PHP scripts run first than javascript. Because php run on server. you can examine what is happening by open source from browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up about your your PHP embedded in your page actually works.  This is a pretty important concept for understanding how your system of PHP, server, Javascript, browser, etc... all work.

PHP runs only on the server.

Javascript in your web page runs only in the browser.

The PHP embedded in your web page runs ONLY once when the page is first created on the server and then when it is sent to the browser, there is NO PHP in the page any more.  It is just Javascript, HTML and CSS at that point.  So calling your `grabLatestRecord()` function does NOT run any PHP.  That was already evaluated on the server when the page was first created.  If you do a View/Source in your browser, you can look at the actual `grabLatestRecord()` function and see that there is no PHP in it in the browser.

If you want to execute some PHP from the web page to get the latest record, then you have to make an Ajax call to your server.  This is kind of like a remote PHP call.  The client Javascript sends a request to your server with an Ajax call.  The server responds to the Ajax call with your results.  The results come back to your Javascript in the browser and you can then update the page contents with your Javascript.

There are zillions of articles on how to set up PHP to handle an Ajax call so I'd suggest you do some reading there and then come back with a new question if you get stuck in doing that.

Comment: Thanks! This is really my first project using PHP and SQLite, so I tried to make it as far as I could without having to ask a question. I'll look into AJAX now!